# Why I am getting this TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on a vehicle counter application in Opencv python, but when I try to draw rectangle on vehicle show I am getting these error, how any help me to fix that..

```
 ret, frame1 = capVideo.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3),5)
    img_sub = carAlgo.apply(blur)
    dillat = cv2.dilate(img_sub, np.ones((5,5)))
    kernal = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5))
    dillData = cv2.morphologyEx(dillat, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernal)
    dillData = cv2.morphologyEx(dillData, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernal)
    countVehcal, h= ( cv2.findContours(dillData, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2. CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE))
    
    #If we pass dilladat in (imshow then it will provide grey effect)
    #to draw a line on the videoView
    cv2.line(frame1,(25, lineLength), (1400, lineLength), (255,127,0),3)

    for (i,c) in enumerate (countVehcal):
        #w=width , z= hight;
        (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        vd_count = (w>=min_rectangle_with) and (h>=min_rectangle_hight)
        if not vd_count:
            continue

    cv2.rectangle(frame1, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,0,255), 2)
    cv2.imshow('Vehical Count', frame1)
```

the error which I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Vehical project\main.py", line 42, in <module>
    cv2.rectangle(frame1, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,0,255), 2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it's because `w` and/or `h` are `None`. Perhaps `countVehcal` is empty, therefore your loop body is not executing? I would check/print its value as well as the values of `w` and `h` before calling `cv2.rectangle(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for answering me, I am new in python can suggest me what changes should I do??

Comment: I would start by simply calling `print` with things. You can pass `print` multiple arguments, and by default, it will print each one separated by a space. For example, try adding the following line before your for loop:
`print("len(countVehcal)", len(countVehcal), "countVehcal", countVehcal, "w:", w, "h:", h)`. What output do you see when you run your code?

Comment: I am getting this output with same error len(countVehcal) 0

Comment: when I remove this line cv2.rectangle(frame1, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,0,255), 2) then I am getting thsi len(countVehcal) 1
len(countVehcal) 0
len(countVehcal) 0
len(countVehcal) 0
len(countVehcal) 57
len(countVehcal) 68
len(countVehcal) 66
len(countVehcal) 0
len(countVehcal) 84
len(countVehcal) 74

Comment: can you provide me your Email or WhatsUp number??, because it is really urgent because it is first year college project.